# Adding onClick event to dynamically generated buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

in Javascript .. If I have a dynamically generated buttons and I want a generic onClick function. How can I do that ?

```
<script>
for(i=0;i<something.length;i++){
   $('body').append('<button id="btnInit'+i+'" >'+i+'</button>');
}
</script>
```

I don't want to create a unique onClick function for each button. How can I do a single one that applies to all. e.g display its label text when pressed.

Comment: just a suggestion: avoid to make multiple DOM insertion in a loop. Make an append() once if possibile, just outside the loop. Or - at least - cache a reference to $('body') for the sake of the perfomance

Comment: Created this fiddle to show you alternate ways to create the buttons; http://jsfiddle.net/eacUJ/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this by using a Javascript feature called "event bubbling". Ancestor elements are notified of events on their descendent elements.

In this case, you can attach a `click` handler to the `body` element and all clicks on those buttons will trigger an event handler.  The nicest way to do this in jQuery is to use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'button', function() {
    alert ('button ' + this.id + ' clicked');
});
```

This will work no matter when the elements are created – before or after the elements were created.

This does exactly the same thing as the `live` method, but `live` uses `on` behind the scenes and is far less efficient and flexible.

Comment: +1 for the on() method. Never knew it before. I've been using live() extensively. This changes everything. Thank you

Comment: @AhmadAlfy That is probably because it's a recent addition to the API, introduced in v. 1.7.0.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a lower version than jQuery 1.7, use `live()`

```
$('input[name^="btnInit"]').live("click", function(){
  alert("clicked");
});
```

for jQuery 1.7+, use `on()`

```
$("body").on("click", "input[name^="btnInit"]", function(){
       alert("clicked");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may delegate the click event to parents of the dynamically created buttons. Here's a great explanation of how it works: http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

In jQuery, you can use the `live` method. refer to its document at http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a live method which will bound event listener to existing elements and those that be created in the future. However this can be written either before or after code where buttons were created

```
$("button[id^=btnInit]").live("click", function(){
    // `this` is reference to each button separately - function will be called many times as how many buttons are
    alert( this.id );
})
```

In newest version of jQuery you can use instead  both `bind` and `live` an `on` method and instead `unbing` and `die` an `off` method.

In jQuery >=1.7

```
   $("body").on( "click","button[id^=btnInit]",  function(){
        // `this` is reference to each button separately - function will be called many times as how many buttons are
        alert( this.id );
    })
```