# Making a javascript modal off AJAX-generated content

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, modal-dialog, dynamically-generated

I have a page where you can search for customers through an ajax search. In the ajax file it chucks all the results from mysql with html into a php var and passes it to JS which sticks it in a div. This part works fine.

Before the ajax was put in, I used a standard html form/php/mysql search. On each row (and still) there is a button to open a modal which is coded below.

```
<button class="button smsModal" id="patient301" fullname="Nathan Ironsi" phone="61425819959"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>&nbsp;sms</button>
```

Now that I am using content generated from the ajax call, this button has stopped working. I have checked the html and I have it formatted the same way as before, but the javascript is not picking up the clicks.

Could someone please explain what mistake I have made? My guess is JS doesn't like pulling html that was not a part of the original page html, but I do not know how to go about fixing this (or if it is indeed possible!)

Modal script:

```
$(".smsModal").on('click', function(){
    $.Dialog({
        overlay: true,
        shadow: true,
        flat: true,
        draggable: false,
        icon: '',
        title: 'SMS',
        content: '',
        padding: 24,
        onShow: function(_dialog){
            var getIdFromButton = $(event.target).attr('id');
            var getFullName = $(event.target).attr('fullname');
            var getPhone = $(event.target).attr('phone');
            var content = 'CONTENT GOES HERE';
            $.Dialog.title("Send SMS to " + getPhone);
            $.Dialog.content(content);
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: I managed to fix this by simply changing this line: `$(".smsModal").on('click', function(){` to `$(document.body).on('click', 'button', function(){`. Yay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by simply changing this line: `$(".smsModal").on('click', function(){` to `$(document.body).on('click', 'button', function(){`.

Thanks to [Adding onClick event to dynamically generated buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702149/adding-onclick-event-to-dynamically-generated-buttons) for the answer!